# Corrupted rendering of Courier New font in Windows Server 2003

Tags: fonts, windows-server-2003, cleartype, opentype

I have two virtual machines with Windows Server 2003 running in VMware Workstation 11.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Unfortunately several days or weeks ago both the machines started to render all four fonts (font styles by MS terminology) in the **Courier New** OpenType typeface in a corrupted way (first example - ClearType ON, second - ClearType OFF):

[image: ClearType ON]
[image: ClearType OFF]

It looks like some horizontal lines of pixels are completely missing in the ClearType rendering. As a result small fonts are unreadable. Other typefaces seem to render normally.

The corresponding font file according to googling of the MD5 looks normally:

```
File:     C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\COUR.TTF
Size:     303,296 bytes
MD5:      72c75860d89e91a517dfb1e7d308c180
Created:  Sunday, 18 February, 2007, 13:00:00
Modified: Sunday, 18 February, 2007, 13:00:00
```

Here is the same problem in the Font Viewer (ClearType ON):

[image: Font Viewer]

I suspect that the problem was caused by one of two recent batches of Microsoft Updates. Could you please recommend how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, it looks like the same problem. Thank you! --- As I use almost only terminals with fixed-width fonts on those machines I did not notice problems with other fonts in my web browsers. I will try to temporarily uninstall the security update 3013455 later. --- I am wondering why I did not find the other question. Bad selection of search keywords... :(

Comment: Your question is better in my opinion.  Should have asked it couple days ago.